# How to open create-react-app from another computer/mobile device outside same network (LAN)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webserver, create-react-app

I want to make my web site accessible outside of my local network. I am developing web site using `Visual Studio Code, NPM/Node.js and react`. Project is created using 'create-react-app' and by default it starts listening on`'localhost:3000 or 127.0.0.1:3000'`.

While debugging, I can access web site from my mobile device using IPv4 address of development computer.
How can I do this when my mobile device is not connected to same LAN with development computer. Instead, it should be connected to mobile network and should reach website using development computers public ip (which we usually find it with websites like this https://www.whatismyip.com/). I want to write browser something like this `'151.135.178.77:3000'` and open web site (without DNS).

In short, I want to use my computer as web server. How can I do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should expose that port in your router control panel to accept connections from outside the network to that running instance. Log in to your router management panel (most likely 192.168.x.1 where x 1-8) and look for NAT/PAT tab somewhere depending on what router are you using, open port and link it to your machine.

Comment: already done that part, but still unable to communicate with nodejs.